# Change parts of code automatically on deployment

Tags: python, flask

I have a small Python flask project that uses SSH tunneling to access a remote database hosted in Pythonanywhere. However, on deployment (to a server that also serves the database), the database has to be accessed without SSH. Does anyone have any tricks on how to make the code "detect" if the code is run on the server vs. on a client? The code is shown below. Currently I have to remember to change the onServer variable before deploying to make the database still accessible.

```
from flask import request, Flask, render_template, send_from_directory, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import sshtunnel

sshtunnel.SSH_TIMEOUT = 5.0
sshtunnel.TUNNEL_TIMEOUT = 5.0

app = Flask(__name__)
app.jinja_env.filters['zip'] = zip
app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 1

onServer = 1
if onServer:
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='mysql://username:password@username.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com/username$default'
    
else:
    # SSH to pythonanywhere to get access to database
    tunnel = sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
        ('ssh.pythonanywhere.com'),
        ssh_username='username',
        ssh_password='password',
        local_bind_address=("127.0.0.1",1000),
        remote_bind_address=('username.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com', 3306)
    )

    # Start SSH tunneling
    tunnel.start()
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='mysql://username:password@127.0.0.1:{}/username$default'.format(tunnel.local_bind_port)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Comment: several options but it comes down to how you discriminate the server from the client. could be as simple as a config file/info that lives on server.

Comment: Maybe even a simple environmental variable like `ON_SERVER=1` on server will also does the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detecting whether you're on the server is an example of *environment* detection: determining what environment your script is running in.

An easy way to provide this information to your script is by using *environment variables*. These can be set on your server, and picked up in your Python code using `os.environ`.

You can get a given environment variable using `os.environ.get()` -- this will return `None` if the variable is not set in the current environment.

```
import os

>>> ON_SERVER = os.environ.get('ON_SERVER')
>>> ON_SERVER
>>> type(ON_SERVER)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Your can compare the result against `None` to get a `True` or `False` value if you prefer (although `None` is already falsey).

```py
>>> ON_SERVER = os.environ.get('ON_SERVER') is not None
>>> ON_SERVER
False
```

Below I set the `ON_SERVER` environment variable in the shell -- here using `export` (Linux/Unix/Mac) you can see the result

```
martin@MacBook ~ % export ON_SERVER=yes
martin@MacBook ~ % python3
Python 3.9.6 (default, Jun 29 2021, 06:20:32)
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> ON_SERVER = os.environ.get('ON_SERVER') is not None
>>> ON_SERVER
True
```

Inside Python, I am now detected as being "on the server" since the environment variable is set.

Note that all environment variables are strings, and all non-empty strings in Python are truthy. So it doesn't matter what you set the environment variable to.